# After importing an older C# file into a new WPF appliction, "using System.Windows;" gives an error message

Tags: c#, wpf

After importing an older C# file into a new WPF appliction, "using System.Windows;" gives an error message.  This wasn't just one C# file, it was a number of them and I put them into a new project.

What reference do I need to locate or change to get using System.Windows to resolve properly?

Answer (score 2):

[Add a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(VS.80).aspx) to System.Drawing for your project.

Comment: I think I'd rather update his library to use WPF functionality instead, but that's definately useful information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This problem stems from resources which are associated at the Project level (References), which I had not added to the new project.

To use old code unchanged, I can [add a Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28VS.80%29.aspx) to System.Drawing, and use the old Windows Forms framework.

If I want to convert the code to WPF, I need to add an association (Reference) to the new project.  I can get `using System.Windows;` to work by adding a Reference in the new project to "PresentationFramework".